# Correct offset for Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, x,y,width,height)

Tags: java, android, bitmap, crop, android-bitmap

I'm having trouble setting a correct offset for my square cropped bitmap. I successfully crop the picture into a square by setting equal width and height, but I also need it to be cropped starting by a certain y offset. I have a relative layout of X height and I would like it to be the offset, so that the square keeps the X top pixel out.
I hope you can help me!

EDIT: An example to clarify my intent:
    For example it there's a picture of a man standing and his head is 400px, then I want the new bitmap to have the man without his head, starting 400px below.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear but shouldn't a simple: `y = offset * (sourceHeight - destHeight)` work? (where offset is between 0.0 and 1.0, 0.0 to align top and 1.0 to align bottom, 0.5 for center align)

Comment: I just want to remove the first (width * Y) pixel from the top of the picture. For example it there's a picture of a man standing and his head is 400px, then I want the new bitmap to have the man without his head, starting 400px below. What do source and destHeight stand for? I have the picture's height and the "part I want to cut out" 's height.

Comment: That's what I though, sourceHeight is the height of the image you're placing and destHeight is the height of the destination area where you're placing it.